# How would i find the position of this array index and also the minimum?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, minimum

How would I complete this program by adding the minimum value of the array, and where the minimum value is located?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input;
    /* A file for the program to open, the absolute location is based on 
     * the location of the project.  /src/array2d/ locates the file in 
     * the current source folder 
     */

    File fileIn = new File("src/array2d/array2dtest1.txt");
    // You can fetch the full absolute path with the method below
    // System.out.println(fileIn.getAbsolutePath());

    /* try...catch is necessary for reading files, as it is possible that
     * the file does not exist.
     */

    try {
        //creating a scanner from the file, rather than using console.
        input = new Scanner(fileIn);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // if file is not found, terminate the program
        System.out.println(fileIn.getName() + " is not found.");
        return;
    }

    int row = input.nextInt();
    int column = input.nextInt();
    int [][] arr = new int[row][column];
    int [] min = arr[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            int k;
            k = arr[i][j];
            System.out.printf("     %3d", k );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    input.close();
    //min
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(i == 1)
        min = arr[i];
    }
    System.out.printf("         min: " + min);
}
```

The output should be:

```
39  95  99  56  41
88  8   1   48  75
3   58  13  54  80
92  72  74  25  86
30  38  3   21  2
```

The minimum is 1, and its position is (whatever the position is)

Comment: Your question and code is not clear. Can you add what data the input file contains?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a new `min` loop for you, stuffed into the loop that does both the rows and columns, with some better style of formatting for your strings as well :)

```
    int min = 0; /* set initial minimum */
    int minRowPos = 0; /* set minimum row and column positions */
    int minColPos = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            int k;
            k = arr[i][j];
            System.out.printf("     %3d", k );
            if(min < arr[i][j]){ /* test and set new min across arr */
                min = arr[i][j];
                minRowPos = i; /* set row position of new minimum */
                minColPos = j; /* set col position of new minimum */
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("Array min: %d at row, column: %d,%d ", min, minRowPos, minColPos);

    }
    input.close();
```

also, delete the declaration of `min` you have at the top

```
int [] min = arr[0];
```

you could be cleaner and move all the declarations to the top of the class if you like, but I didn't want to clutter things up any more and keep it a small chunk of change.

Comment: im getting an error.  it says     if(min < arr[i]){   contains a bad operand?

Comment: if you're satisfied that it solves your problem, please mark the answer as complete to clear it and help others find answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
//min
int i;
int pos;
for(i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(i == 1)
    min = arr[i];
  pos = i;
}
System.out.printf("         min: " + min + " position " + pos );
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your code `int [] min = arr[0];` should give you an error because you cannot have a reference variable of type int[ ] reference to int.

Now to the answer :

```
<java>
int minimum = arr[0];
int minimum_index = 0
for(int i = 1;i<arr.length;i++){
     if(arr[i]<minimum){      // Found an array element lesser than previously recorded minimum
         minimum = arr[i];   //update the recorded minimum
         minimum_index = i;  // update the recorded minimum index
      }
 }
 System.out.printf("Array minimum %d found at %d",minimum,minimum_index);
```